# Manipulation of the text between two parents

Tags: html, bash, sed

i have following html text where number of "tr's" is dynamic:

```
<tr>
    <td>Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type=button value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type=button value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type=button value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and i would like to get following result:

```
Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3 
Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3 
Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
```

i tried to use sed to group by :

```
sed '/^<tr>/d;:a;N;/^<\/tr>/M!s/\n/ /;ta;P;d'
```

but of course it doesn't work. Any suggestion how to deal with that?

Comment: Use an HTML parser.

Comment: Bad idea to use bash to parse HTML

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want a <s>quick and</s> dirty solution, parsing html should be done using html parser as being said in comments.

For example, using python:

```
import bs4 # bs4 stands for beautifulsoup, a html parser
import csv

# I open both input and output file
with open(<input>) as myinput, open(<output>, "w") as myoutput:
    # I parse the html
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(myinput, 'html.parser')
    # I set the delimiter for the csv
    csvwriter = csv.writer(myoutput, delimiter="|")

    # For each tr tag
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        # Here I create a list that contains all text from td
        rows = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
        # I write the 4th first values as a csv row
        csvwriter.writerow(rows[:4])
```

Now if you are not convinced with this nice solution, let's have a look to a <s>quick and</s> dirty one using awk:

```
awk '
   # I define here input and output delimiters
   BEGIN{FS="<|>"; OFS=" | "}
   # I store info in array td_info
   /<td>/{td_info[++counter]=$3} 
   # I print the info I need and clean td_info array and counter
   /<\/tr>/{
       print td_info[1], td_info[2], td_info[3], td_info[4]
       counter=0
       delete td_info
   }
' <input.html>
```

Output :

```
Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely different approach - just to give you a flavor of XSLT.  I'm usually not a fan of XSLT to be honest, and frankly it's not good for the HTML example you have provided.  In fact, it's a bad match for this problem, but it would be good to add it to the discussion.

First, HTML is not strictly XML compatible.  But in this case, it would be interesting to note what I had to do to your input to make it XML compatible:

1. Quote 'button'.  So now the type attribute on the input elements is quoted:

   <input type='button'... >
2. I had to wrap all the  elements in a root element.  I chose <table> but I could have chosen nearly anything.

Here's an XSLT approach:

```
function xsl {
cat  <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:mpd="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="locale">en</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="//tr"><xsl:value-of select="td[1]"/> | <xsl:value-of select="td[2]"/> | <xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/> | <xsl:value-of select="td[4]"/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
}

xsltproc <( xsl ) -  <<EOF
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM</td>
    <td>some text1</td>
    <td>some text2</td>
    <td>some text3</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onCLick="add(12345)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
EOF
```

And here's the output on the MAC:

```
Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3

Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3

Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, please use a HTML parser, like [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for instance.

> Xidel is a command line tool to download and extract data from
>   HTML/XML pages as well as JSON-APIs, using CSS, XPath 3.0, XQuery 3.0,
>   JSONiq or pattern templates. It can also create new or transformed
>   XML/HTML/JSON documents.

```
xidel -s input.html -e '//tr/join(td[position()<5]," | ")'
Dec 1, 2019 11:12 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
Dec 5, 2019 4:33 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
Dec 9, 2019 1:06 PM | some text1 | some text2 | some text3
```

In human terms: for every `tr`-node select the text-node of the first 4 `td`-nodes and join them together separated by a `|`.

See also [this xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3EDec%201%2C%202019%2011%3A12%20PM%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text1%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text2%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text3%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3Dbutton%20value%3D%22Add%22%20id%3D%22add%22%20onCLick%3D%22add(12345)%22%20data-toggle%3D%22modal%22%20data-target%3D%22%23add%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3EDec%205%2C%202019%204%3A33%20PM%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text1%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text2%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text3%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3Dbutton%20value%3D%22Add%22%20id%3D%22add%22%20onCLick%3D%22add(12345)%22%20data-toggle%3D%22modal%22%20data-target%3D%22%23add%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3EDec%209%2C%202019%201%3A06%20PM%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text1%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text2%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3Esome%20text3%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20type%3Dbutton%20value%3D%22Add%22%20id%3D%22add%22%20onCLick%3D%22add(12345)%22%20data-toggle%3D%22modal%22%20data-target%3D%22%23add%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%0A&=&extract=%2F%2Ftr%2Ftd%5Bposition()%3C5%5D%2C%0A%22%22%2C%0A%2F%2Ftr%2Fjoin(td%5Bposition()%3C5%5D%2C%22%20%7C%20%22)%0A&=%5Bposition()%3C5%5D&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/<tr>/{:a;x;/\n/{s/<\/?t[rd]>/\n/g;s/^\s.*//mg;s/\n+/ | /g;s/^...|...$//g;p};x;h;d};//!H;$!d;ba' file
```

Gather up lines between `<tr>` and `<\tr>` into the hold space. If the hold space already contains lines when a `<tr>` tag is encountered, manipulate the collection into the required format: replace tags by newlines, remove lines that begin with white space, replace one or more newlines by `|` and top and tail the first 3 characters artifacts and print the manufactured record.